# Python: str.split string returning 'Columns must be same length as key' despite expand=True and no multiple matches for regex in string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've been working on this for a while now and it doesn't make a lot of sense to me

I have some coordinate data that comes in the form of:

"4.970599399999999, 'lng': -1.6918635"

The first part is the latitude, and the second the longitude.

This is the column:

```
 coordinates
  4.970599399999999, 'lng': -1.6918635
  None
  4.5, 'lng': -1.69
  4.9705, 'lng': -1.6
  None
```

The code i'm using is:

```
data[['latitude','longitude']] = data['coordinates'].str.split('\,\s\'lng\'\w*\:\s',expand=True)
```

I've used Regexr to confirm that my regex is perfectly fine and splitting on the right delimiter and there isn't a problem there

But the error i'm getting is this:

"ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"

I have experienced this error before and I found it was due to having multiple matches in the string - but these strings are short and simple! It's either 'None' or the coordinates

Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: data is a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method works for me on pandas v0.22. However, I would instead go with the more idiomatic `str.extract` here:

```
p = r'(?P<latitude>-?\d+\.\d+).*?(?P<longitude>-?\d+\.\d+)'
df[['latitude', 'longitude']] = df['coordinates'].str.extract(p, expand=True)

df
                            coordinates           latitude   longitude
0  4.970599399999999, 'lng': -1.6918635  4.970599399999999  -1.6918635
1                                  None                NaN         NaN
2                     4.5, 'lng': -1.69                4.5       -1.69
3                   4.9705, 'lng': -1.6             4.9705        -1.6
4                                  None                NaN         NaN
```

With `str.extract` you may specify named capture groups.

Comment: VCould you explain why my original wasn't though? Why should I use this method over yours in the future? Thanks again

Comment: @MassiveOwl It's either your actual generating more than 2 splits, or possibly a bug from an older pandas version, because it worked for me for this sample -- although that regex is a mess.

Comment: @MassiveOwl As to why you should use extract, well, it's a lot more readable in terms of the regex it uses and what it is trying to do. Furthermore, it guarantees a two column result. In your actual data, str.split could generate, 1, 2, or 100 columns,  depending on your data.